# pull xml rss feed from ncbi

Tags: php, rss, ncbi

so i have this search http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=Streptococcus+dysgalactiae+subspecies+equisimilis and i want to get the rss feed(not manually), like a string with the xml, but i want to do it using php. ive tryed to search for a method on ncbi but i guess im not very good at it..

do i have to search in the html for the href? or something like this [getting RSS feeds on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074795/getting-rss-feeds-on-website) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feed URL for the search isn't contained on the page. Clicking 'Create RSS' makes a call to the server to store the search terms and returns a feed with a new `rss_guid`. If there isn't an API to call you would need to examine the JavaScript and simulate a browser clicking on that button.

(As an implementation detail, the site returns different `guid`s even when the search is the same, which implies that each 'Create RSS' is creating a new resource.)